# Handling indirect vulnerable 3rd party dependencies

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, node.js

How would one go about fixing vulnerabilities in indirect 3rd party libraries? Let's say that the vulnerability is introduced via the following chain:

Introduced through:

```
example-app› express-prometheus-middleware@0.9.6 › prometheus-gc-stats@0.6.3 › gc-stats@1.4.0 › node-pre-gyp@0.13.0 › rc@1.2.8 › ini@1.3.5
```

The vulnerability is in ini@1.3.5 and is fixed in ini@1.3.6 but the Prometheus middleware library does not have a version where that is upgraded. What is the best strategy to fix such a vulnerability?

Comment: Have you checked out the [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) package?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is figure out if you're vulnerable to the vulnerability. Based on how you use the dependencies, you may not be vulnerable. Any of the dependencies along the way may also not use the dependency in such a way that exposes the vulnerability or have other mitigations in place. If this is the case, you may not have to do anything.

If you are vulnerable, determine if there's something you can do. Can you provide mitigations in code that you control? If not, can you make a contribution to the downstream libraries to upgrade them, or at least raise an issue to ensure the maintainers know about the vulnerability that has been patched so they can update their dependencies?

The existence of a vulnerability in and of itself may not be that meaningful. It should trigger a deeper investigation to understand the risks, impacts, and potential actions to mitigate the threat (if a threat exists).

Comment: 100% agree, but there is some nuance you missed. Your advice assumes a strict linear relationship to threats. If the vulnerable library ends up getting called by something *else*, especially later on after your assessment ("oh, look, we already have `ini`, let's call it") then you've exposed yourself. Some other measures need to be taken to isolate the vulnerable library from other uses, too, else you plant a landmine in your code.

Comment: @schroeder Yes, that is true. I've usually solved that by making sure everyone is aware of the vulnerable packages that exist in the system to check before using a transitive dependency directly (the information is available in a tool with a dashboard). It's still a manual process to check and stay informed on known vulnerabilities in a package that you decide to use directly to make sure you stay mitigated, so there may be better ways. I'd suspect the "better ways" depend on your environment (language, framework, tooling, etc.).

Comment: @schroeder I'll also say that there's something to be said for applying "do not use transitive dependencies directly". Having a lightweight review process for new top-level dependencies that includes a vulnerability assessment helps. Plus, you can bring in a newer version that should be patched.